# Python: Warning intalling pip on windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

here is the message i get when i try to install pip (to install python packages) on windows 10 on my command prompt:

```
Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-20.2.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.5 MB)
Collecting setuptools
  Downloading setuptools-49.6.0-py3-none-any.whl (803 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 803 kB 1.3 MB/s
Installing collected packages: pip, setuptools
  WARNING: The scripts pip.exe, pip3.8.exe and pip3.exe are installed in 'C:\Users\GMU\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The scripts easy_install-3.8.exe and easy_install.exe are installed in 'C:\Users\GMU\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed pip-20.2.2 setuptools-49.6.0
```

What does it mean ?
It says it installed but when i try the

> pip --version

command or `

> pip

i have  message saying that pip is not a recognize command.

Thank's for your help.

Comment: Additional information: I'm on 3.8.0 python version

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue an the solution too.

First in not English native so at the first read in didn't get it.

The path where I've installed python wasn't good or something like that so pip couldn't retrieved it properly. The message is more or less clear about that fact.

Here is what I did:

1. uninstall pip
2. uninstall python 3.8.0
3. install python 3.8.5 with personalized config (not the recommended) because the install exe wanted to install python to the same folder than the last version. So I choose `"C:\Program"` and install Pip too with the prompt installer in order to get it to same folder.

Now it works fine for me.

Morality => don't install python to this path `C:\Users\GMU\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\..`

Answer (score 0):

Windows is recommending you to add python to your PATH.
When you add python to your PATH, you will be able to execute pip in your command prompt.

I would recommend having a look at this https://geek-university.com/python/add-python-to-the-windows-path/.

Comment: Yes Python was already added to my environnement on Windows. The issue wasn't there